# How to override sonata admin bundle templates in symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

I am using symfony 4.1, just want to override templates generated by sonata admin bundle.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer this links to override template in symfony 4.
[Override template in symfony 4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates)

override for sonata admin use refer this link.
[Override sonata admin template](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/reference/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

Example of edit pages template overriding in symfony 4.4 and sonata 3.81:

`config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        # custom tpl is located in /templates/admin/global/edit.twig
        edit: '/admin/global/edit.twig'
```

`/templates/admin/global/edit.twig`

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block sonata_form_actions %}
    # copy-paste original file code and customize it
{% endblock %}
```